# jQueryUI DatePicker Validation

Tags: validation, datepicker, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to validate the date fields so when you if you select a date in the future and in the second input box you select today's date it should not let you submit the form.

I have it working so you cant select yesterday's date - its the date comparison that i cant seem to get working.

```
/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"/>
/js/jquery.validate.js" />
/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput validBeforeDatepicker" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput validAfterDatepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});

 $('.validBeforeDatepicker,.validAfterDatepicker').datepicker();


$(function () {
    $(".DatepickerInput").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: 0,
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#validAfterDatepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: +1,
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'            
    });
});
```

I'm following this example but I'm going wrong somewhere and cant seem to quite put my finger on what it could be.

Website: http://bit.ly/WdZf10

Please dont submit form as it will just be spam if testing the form on the website. You can see its not validating even before submitting the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for the problem and probably less code used for it as well. Thought I'd share so if anyone gets stuck they can use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    function getDiff() {
        var from = $(".start").val();
        var till = $(".fin").val();
        var c = from.split("/");
        beg = new Date(c[2], c[1] - 1, c[0]);
        var d = till.split("/");
        en = new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0]);
        var rest = (en - beg) / 86400000;
        var txt = rest == 0 ? "" : rest + " days"
        $("#res").text(txt);
    }

    $(".start").datepicker({
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        showAnim: "fadeIn",
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate: 0, //change this to +3 to start 3 days from now
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(".fin").val(dateText);
            $(".fin").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
            getDiff();
        }
    });

    $(".fin").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "fadeIn",
        onSelect: getDiff
    });
});
```